# How can i access value of a bool variable from a different screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get the boolean value from a different screen.

in screen1  i have :

```
Future<void> _verifyPuchase(String id) async {
    PurchaseDetails purchase = _hasPurchased(id);
    if (purchase != null && purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
      print(purchase.productID);
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        await _iap.completePurchase(purchase);
        print('Achats antérieurs........$purchase');
        isPuchased = true;
      }
      isPuchased = true;
    } else {
      isPuchased = false;
    }
  }
```

and on screen2 i have :

```
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.call), onPressed: () => onJoin("AudioCall")),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.video_call),
                onPressed: () => onJoin("VideoCall")),
```

i am trying to get the value of isPuchased on screen2 , meaning when the any of the icon buttons are tapped on the screen2 then it first verifies the value of isPuchased and if its true then proceed with the normal execution of the function onJoin() and if its false then dont proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way

**first page:**

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>SecondPage(isPuchased)));
```

**second page:**

```
 class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isPuchased;
  SecondPage(this.isPuchased);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SecondPageState();
  }
}
class SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //now you have passing variable
        title: Text("title"),
      ),
      body:Column(children: [
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.call), onPressed: () {
      if(widget.isPuchased)  onJoin("AudioCall");
    } ),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.video_call),
            onPressed: () {
               if(widget.isPuchased)  onJoin("VideoCall");
            }),
      ],),
    );
  }

}
```

and note your problrm is a state management problem you have to search about "state managment in flutter" either using the traditional way passing the data with you in constructor until you reach the desired page, or use state management like Bloc or Provider

Comment: sorry for a stupid question , i am total noob , but isnt the material page rout used to navigate between screens ? will this work ? since screen2 isnt necessarily has to open after screen1 , i am trying to use the variable to see if user has a subscription if yes then user can use the call feature otherwise no , will this be a suitable solution in this scenario?

Comment: yes Navigator for routing and also can pass data.

your problrm is a state management issue you have to search about "state managment in flutter"

either using the traditional way passing the data with you in constructor until you reach the desired page,

or use state management like Bloc or Provider

Comment: ahhh okay , i was actually kinda hoping for a simple solution since i am still just a newbie in flutter , but i guess it cant be done with a simple method

Comment: once you learn state management it will be easy :) ,

Comment: and if your question is answered pls upvote and accept the question as answered

Comment: I guess i will dig right into state management then